# Linux - Perl - file doesn't exist, yet it does

Tags: linux, perl

I have a file at

```
/var/tmp/pcaps/è¨€èªžã‚’é¸æŠžã—ã¦ããŸã‚™.pcap'
```

That's exactly the name of it, it's encoded in UTF-8.

When I run vim on it, it opens up as expected.

But when I run the following piece of perl code:

```
    if (-e $target_file) {
            warn "the file exists\n";
    } else {
            warn "the file does not exist!\n";
    }
```

$target_file being exactly the file mentioned above. It goes into else.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have: use utf8?

Comment: Is your script saved as utf8 (if you're on linux, run `file your_script.pl` to find out). Is the name of the file hard-coded in your script? If not, how do you get it?

Comment: A full program that shows the result would help everyone answer your question.

Comment: 1) Please provide the output of `CORE::say(sprintf("%vX", $target_file)."-".(utf8::is_utf8($target)?1:0));`. (Note that `utf8::is_utf8` should NEVER be used outside of debugging.)

Comment: 2) Please provide the output of `CORE::say(sprintf("%vX", $_)) for glob '/var/tmp/pcaps/*.pcap';`

Answer (score 1):

```
#use utf8;
my $file = 'è¨èªãé¸æãã¦ããã.pcap';
if(-e $file){
    print "exists\n";
}
```

This worked for me. Maybe try "use utf8;"

EDIT:

check the full path of $target_file.
Maybe there is a wrong letter/folder?